# Kafka Consumer delay

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I'm having the following problem:

I'm recieving messages produced by the producer with a delay (somtimes up to a minute). I have no control over the producer, and I want to make sure that everythings working in order on my side.

I'm using `kafka-client` version 0.11.0.0. Version change is possible but tedious, so I want to avoid changing versions as much as possible.

My consumer config looks like this:

```
group.id= unique-group-d
bootstrap.servers = # kafka broker with version 0.11.0.0
auto.offset.reset = latest
# avoid client id collision with Kafka
client.id= some-example-gateway-client
```

And I'm polling for messages like this:

```
ConsumerRecords<String, String> tConsumerRecords = tempConsumer.poll(1000);
tempMessage.forEach(entry -> {
    [...]
});
```

There are 100% no name collisions with the client nor group id. The topic which I'm subscribing has only 1 partition.

I doubt the producer is under heavy load, its a separate enviroment with sporadic messages begin produced by that producer.

It does not help that its friday and everyone is already gone.

Have I missing something ? Can I shift the blame onto the producer side ?

Comment: try to use kafka-console-consumer.sh script to read from very same topic to verify if messages are there with higher frequency

Comment: Use above, as well as check Kafka lag API to see regularly if there are any unprocessed msgs for your consumer group: kafka-consumer-groups --bootstrap-server <server:9092> --describe --group <unique-group-d>

Answer (score 0):

*As of Kafka v0.10 each message contains a meta data timestamp attribute, that is either set by the producer on message creation time, or by the broker on message insertion time.*

There is an interface provided `org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.TimestampExtractor` and it has a method `extract` that extracts a timestamp from a record.

Basically, you just need to compare timestamp both at producer and consumer end to make sure if messages are delayed from producer side or on consumer side.

**Source:**
https://kafka.apache.org/10/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/processor/TimestampExtractor.html

https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#topicconfigs